# From Rails & Backbone to ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, client-side

I'm trying out ember js on a personal project. I'm struggling with understanding what part plays the different components of Ember.

I'm quite familiar with Rails, and I've used backbone to some extent (never used everything related to routing), and get how the two of them work, and what kind of objects plays which part of MVC.

With Ember, things are not that clear and seems a bit less easy. I've read the guides and a few posts, but I'm still struggling to get going. I get the model part, which is fairly similar to its rails and backbone counterpart. I get templates, handlebars, that stuff too. The router is similar to rails router.

Then there is Controllers, Routes, and Views. From what I understood, Views represent a portion of the ui, and handles user interaction. It's the controller/routes roles that I don't get very much.

To be more concrete: I want my app to have a nav bar (with links to page sections), and a "user connexion widget", displaying user data if he's connected, allow him to do so if not, log in via facebook etc.

The navbar seems appropriate for a View, however I need to keep the state somewhere (to highlight the current page), which seems to be the controller role. And the user widget seems appropriate for a controller, but there's only one controller per route, so how to do this ?

Thanks a lot for your time, I hope I was clear enough!

:)

Answer (score 1):

Controller stores the state of your application. Router manages different states of your application. You're correct, there's only one controller per route, but you can access other controllers as well.

Assuming this your html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="main-content">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="user">
      {{#if isLoggedIn}}
        <div class="user-name">{{userName}}</div>
        {{else}}
        <button {{action "login" target="App.UserController"}}>
            Login
        </button>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">some other amazing content here</div>
</script>
```

and JS:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  rootElement: '#ember-app'
});

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('user');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controller.set('isLoggedIn', this.controllerFor('user').get('isLoggedIn'));
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userName: 'emberjs',
  login: function () {
     this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
  }
});

App.NavbarView = Ember.View.create({
  loggedInBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.UserController.isLoggedIn')
});
```

If you need to access another controller from your route, you can do this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(function () {
  setupController: function () {
    var userController = this.controllerFor('user');
    console.log('this is a user controller instance', userController);
  }
});
```